# Aspectj alternative to this

Tags: android, aspectj

I am new with Aspectj. My problem is that I would like to get the Activity (or the Context) of my MainApp in Android without modifying my original code. I have this:

```
public class SensorTestActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
  private SensorManager sensorManager;
  private boolean color = false;
  private View view;
  private long lastUpdate;
 //public static Context context;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensor_test);
    view = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //context=this;
  }
```

Now with Aspectj what I want to do is to add the two commented lines and get the Context and work with it. Something like:

```
public aspect Trace extends Application{

    private static Context SensorTestActivity.mContext;

    pointcut inicio(Bundle bundle) : execution(* ..onCreate*(..)) && args(bundle);
    void around(Bundle bundle): inicio(bundle){
        //System.out.println("I'm  in onCreate");
        SensorTestActivity.mContext= this;
        proceed(bundle);

    }
```

The problem is that I cannot use "this". If you know how to do that, or if there is another way to get the Context in the .aj file I'll be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use the [JoinPoint](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html). It provides reflective access to the advised object, allowing you to use and/or modify it.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried with that but always occurred a problem. Now it is working with thisJoinPoint.getThis(). Thankyou again